# Excel VBA Ctrl-Shift-Enter array function very slow compared to writing long worksheet function

Tags: arrays, excel, vba, performance, function

I have written a function `NA_2_X(Range, Variant)` to accept an array, convert all `#NA` to a Variant, and return the new array:

```
{=NA_2_X(A1:A3000, 0)}
```

This is giving much slower execution than writing a laborious worksheet function:

```
{=IF(ISNA(A1:A3000), 0, A1:A3000)}
```

300 calls to `NA_2_X()` takes about 10s, whereas the `IF()` statement is almost instant. Ultimately I want to do something more complicated and can't use an `if()` statement.

```
Function NA_2_X(ByVal rng As Range, ByVal X As Variant) As Variant
    Dim NoRows As Long, NoCols As Long
    Dim r As Long, c As Long
    Dim ret() As Variant

    NoRows = rng.Rows.Count
    NoCols = rng.Columns.Count

    ReDim ret(1 To NoRows, 1 To NoCols)

    For c = 1 To NoCols
        For r = 1 To NoRows
            If Application.IsNA(rng(r, c)) Then
                ret(r, c) = X
            Else
                ret(r, c) = rng(r, c)
            End If
        Next r
    Next c

    NA_2_X = ret
    Exit Function
End Function
```

The loop itself seems pretty quick, it is just the few lines in the heart of the loop that seem so slow. If I remove the call to `IsNA()` it takes about half the time, but is still slow.

Comment: Not quite sure what you mean (I'm no VBA expert). I did try Dim tmp as Variant, tmp=rng(r,c) and then referencing tmp instead. It helped a bit but not a lot.

Comment: `Dim tmp() as Variant`, then `tmp = rng.Value`. Then loop through temp (use `LBound` and `UBound` to determine bounds,  instead of `NoRows` and `NoCols`. This will be faster (though can't guarantee it will be as fast as a normal function).

Comment: What about using `SpecialCells` which has an error parameter (though can't distinguish NA from others).

Comment: tmp.rng.Value helps, it reduces the time per call from 32ms to 15ms, but unfortunately it is still too slow. It seems that Application.IsNA(tmp(r,c)) is very slow, not sure why.

Comment: `arr = .Evaluate("IF(ISNA(" & Rng.Address & ")," & X & "," & Rng.Address & ")")` would give you an array of values. I'm also not sure what exactly you would want to do so maybe the suggested line is pointless

Answer (score 0):

In addition to BigBen's suggestion, replacing "Application.IsNA(rng(r,c))" with "IsError(tmp(r,c))" has made the routine nice and fast.